# Make a search form to search with http api

Tags: http, search

i am new to this matter. I am trying to create a search form, that allows searching a database via http api and display the result on a website. The call requires authorization:

```
$headers = array ('headers' => array( 
                  'Authorization' =>       'bearer' . $token  ,
                  'Content-type'  =>       'application/json',
                  'Accept'        =>       'application/json'));
```

My search form looks like this:

```
<form method="GET" accept="application/json" action="https://example.xx/api/v1/products?page=1&size=5&direction=asc&search=value">
  <input type="text" name="search" size="40" maxlength="256" value="" placeholder="testsearch">
  <input type="submit" name="search_button" value="Search">
</form>
```

When i enter something into the input field and hit the submit button, the browser displays:

```
{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}
```

And in the browsers address field i see:

```
https://example.xx/api/v1/products?search=testvalue&search_button=Search
```

Obviously the authorisation is ignored and the url shows that i have left my website.

Do i have to make this work with an action="somephp.php"?
How can i authorize the call from the form and display the response in a website?
Hints much appreciated. theo

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the german wordpress forum, i found the answer –
The Form:

```
<form method="post" id="api-result-searchform" action="">
    <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Author?', 'placeholder' ) ?>" value="" name="searchauthor" id="s" title="api-search" />
    <input class="button"type="submit" name="search_button" value="Search">
</form>
```

And the call:

```
<?php
    $searchterm = $_POST['searchauthor'];
    $url = 'https://example.de/api/v1/product?search=ti=' . $searchterm;
    $response = wp_remote_get($url, $headers);
    //etc.
```

This works well.